# How to start "save as / open" after requesting a file from server?

Tags: download, request, mootools

I'm using MooTools as JS-Framework.

When a user clicks the "Show Report"-Button on my website I'm starting **Request.HTML** to retrieve the path of the requested report.

If the report does not exists yet, its been created on the server (a waiting popup is shown to the user). The report file is saved to a special path on the server and this path is returned to the browser.

After I got the path to the Report-File - the Report can reach about 5 to 8MB - I want to show the user a "Download-ProgressBar" while starting a new Request.HTML to retrieve the big report file.

Everthing until this point works fine. I got the ProgressBar filling up, after its finished I got my big file.

But my problem is now, how I can start something like "Open File" or "Save File As" from JavaScript.

I got the freaking file downloaded and shown in the console but now I want the user to save this file somewhere or to open it directly...

[image]

Kind Regard.

Comment: Mario please remember to mark answer as accepted if they solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just show a link to that file so that it opens in a new page? 
That way one can open in a new window and save from the browser's menu (or use the right click>save to menu).

Since you already have your file serialized most browsers nowadays [supports the data uri scheme](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)  so if this fine to support a limited subset of browsers you can do

```
window.open(fileToSave, '_blank');
```

notably old version of IE don't support all kind of files using data-uri so it will not work for html.

There are some File API in newer browser too, and there are some other solutions involving flash but historically the right way to do this is to navigate to a server page which returns an header

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=yourfilename.html
```

that will work in any browser (I used this a lot in IE6 with no particular problem).